# iOS 9 changed view load behaviour

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios9, viewwillappear

I have noticed a change in how iOS 9 loads/displays views compared to previous versions of iOS. Here's an output of `self.view.frame` in `iOS 8.4`

```
viewDidLoad {{0, 0}, {320, 504}}
viewWillAppear {{0, 64}, {320, 504}}
viewDidAppear {{0, 64}, {320, 504}}
```

And here's the same for `iOS 9`

```
viewDidLoad {{0, 0}, {320, 504}}
viewWillAppear {{0, 0}, {320, 504}}
viewDidAppear {{0, 64}, {320, 504}}
```

Notice that in `viewWillAppear` method `iOS 9` fails to update the `origin` of `self.view.frame`.

This causes certain issues in my app such as views initially being position incorrectly.

Does anyone know if it's intended or it's a defect? And perhaps a quick fix?

Comment: Why would this change be a problem for you? Subviews should be positioned based on the bounds, not frame, of their parent view. That won't be different here.

Comment: Good point, only I'm handling the position of a `UITabBar` (showing in some screens, hiding in others), which is not a subview of `self.view`. Besides, `iOS 9` fails to update view size as well as origin.

Comment: The output you show indicates that the view size is updated. It's 504 in both versions of iOS.

Comment: On another screen I have `viewDidLoad {{0, 0}, {600, 536}}`, `viewWillAppear {{0, 0}, {600, 536}}`, `viewDidAppear {{0, 64}, {320, 504}}` for `iOS 9`

Comment: BTW, your first comment led me to try and use `[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]` instead of relying on `self.view.frame`. This indeed helped me avoid the negative effects of this change in `iOS 9`, so thanks.

Comment: Don't use UIScreen as your application doesn't allows fill the screen as in the case of slide over and split view on iPad.

Comment: Is it safe to use for iPhone-only though? If not, what is an alternative?

Comment: You should be using self.view.bounds to position your subviews, not self.view.frame.

Answer (score 2):

I found the same change in iOS 9 versus previous iOS versions: in viewWillAppear, self.view.frame and self.view.bounds only show the default size used in the nib instead of the size actually used at runtime. This means if, for example, your nib has a default width of 320 but you run it on an iPhone 6, the width will be incorrectly reported as 320 instead of 375.

You could use [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds], as suggested in the comments to the question, but that would only work if your views always fill the screen. If you have a split-screen design on an iPad and you need to know the actual display width of an individual view, it is not available in viewWillAppear.

You could use viewWillLayoutSubviews instead of viewWillAppear, because the frame and bounds are correctly set at that point. However, this is not called every time a view appears, only when it first appears, so your app behavior will change slightly.

I'm using a combination of viewWillAppear and viewWillLayoutSubviews, along with a new instance variable, to replicate the pre-iOS 9 behavior in iOS 9:

```
@synthesize sizingReady;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // set a flag telling us whether the view size is available
    // this is needed in iOS 9 because the view size isn't updated in viewWillAppear yet
    self.sizingReady = FALSE;
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    // don't do anything until the view size is available, which doesn't happen until viewWillLayoutSubviews in iOS 9
    if (!self.sizingReady) {
        return;
    }

    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    // your code goes here
}

- (void)viewWillLayoutSubviews {
    [super viewWillLayoutSubviews];

    if (!self.sizingReady) {
        self.sizingReady = TRUE;
        [self viewWillAppear:TRUE];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can method swizzling viewWillAppear: , and use screen bounds

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    self.view.frame = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds;
}
```

or

```
- (void)viewDidLoad:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidLoad:animated];

    self.view.frame = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds;
}
```